# saving multiple dicts and variables in disk

Tags: python, json, pickle

My code typically runs  for several days and spews out intermediate results as Python dicts and float variables. I cannot afford to append all intermediate values to a Python list and save all outputs to a  physical file using pickle etc in one go after the run. This is because, in case there is interruption, I might loose all data I have collected so far.

So I have to dump (and append) multiple dicts and other variables periodically. What is the best way to do this ? I've looked at JSON (but not sure how to do store (and later read)  multiple JSON objects from a single file. Can I append my data to a pickle file ? Saving these data in a simple text file or csv file would be my last resort.

Comment: You can append pickles to a file and then read them one by one until you get `EOFError`, like in this [code](https://github.com/ciupicri/bac-parser/blob/f00d9562f9a8f4f9bf475fb3773db34ee12021e5/pickle2csv.py#L38).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this do depend on your requirement

1. does the appending data needs to refer the previous one

   - if so, and you can't afford data loss cause by possibly file handler error, you might consider to keep the data in a sqlite database, python comes with it
   - if not, you could just simply create new json files, and problem solved, merge them when necessary
2. using pickle

   - i do found some StringIO in pickle document, and just mentioned needs file handler for write, not sure if it supports 'append', whether just directly append the binary data / picked string using python file handler append or system >>

Answer (score 4):

Use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). This is a good variant for conservation with the ability to edit the file:

```
import json

list_of_dict = [
    {'a': 1},
    {'b': 2}
]

with open('filename.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list_of_dict, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: This implies that I compile all my dicts into a single list and then write this to a JSON file, which is what I cannot afford to do.  Is it possible to continuously append multiple JSON objects into a single file, and then parse this file to re-load all JSON objects into a Python List ?